# Is it possible to automatically stringify in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know I can create a `toString()` function on an object, so that every time it's printed or treated like a string it will first stringify the object with that function.

Is it possible to do that directly so I can use String object functions on the object?

```
var SomeObject = function(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b
}

SomeObject.prototype.toString = function(){
    return [ this.a, this.b ].join(' ')
}

var objInstance = new SomeObject('this', 'that');

console.log(objInstance + '')                // This that
console.log(("" + objInstance).split(''))    // [ 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'a', 't' ]
console.log(objInstance.split())             // Error
```

Is it possible to do so that the object "behaves" like a string when a String function is called on it?

In other words, I'd like `objInstance.split()` to have the same result as `("" + objInstance).split('')`, and also `objInstance.length` or `objInstance.match(/something/)`, etc.

Comment: So you want to be able to concatenate all values of an object and search through it. You're doing it for searching purpose right ?

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to do with this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can let your objects inherit from `String` so that all string methods become available:

```js
class SomeObject extends String {
  constructor(a, b) {
    super(a + " " + b);
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}

var obj = new SomeObject('this', 'that');
console.log(obj.split(""));
```

No need to use complicated `Proxy` solutions :-)

All the `String.prototype` methods (except for `.toString`, `.valueOf` and `[Symbol.iterator]`) are "*intentionally generic; [they do] not require that its `this` value be a `String` object. Therefore, [they] can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.*" You can call them on any value, they will coerce it to a string (using `.toString()` or `.valueOf` as usual).

You don't even need to use ES6 `class extends` to inherit from the builtin (which also makes your string value immutable), it works in ES5 as well:

```js
function SomeObject(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
SomeObject.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype);
SomeObject.prototype.constructor = SomeObject;
SomeObject.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.a + " " + this.b;
};

var obj = new SomeObject('this', 'that');
console.log(obj.split(""));
```

Comment: Is this considered good practice? It seems like a misuse of inheritance.

Comment: @usr Maybe it is, I don't know the OPs use case. However, if they want all of `String`s methods on their custom instances, that sounds quite a bit like subtyping.

Answer (score 22):

One option would be to return a `Proxy` that checks whether the property exists on `String.prototype`, and if it does, calls that property with the string that represents the object:

```js
// Declare the proxy handler up front here
// to avoid unnecessary creation of duplicate handler objects
const handler = {
  get(obj, prop) {
    if (obj[prop] !== undefined) {
      return obj[prop];
    }
    const stringMethod = String.prototype[prop];
    if (stringMethod) {
      return stringMethod.bind(obj.a + ' ' + obj.b);
    }
  },
};

const SomeClass = function(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b
  return new Proxy(this, handler);
}

const instance = new SomeClass('this', 'that');

// String methods:
console.log(instance.trim());
console.log(instance.includes('this'));
console.log(instance.includes('somethingelse'));
console.log(instance.split(''));

// Can still assign and retrieve values directly on the object as normal:
instance.foo = 'foo';
console.log(instance.foo);
```

Comment: +1. Remark: this definition is only available in ecmascript 6 or later. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: I would recommend to declare the handler object outside of the constructor function, for the same reason that you should define methods on the prototype. Then you'd also use the `target` argument instead of closing over `this`.

Answer (score 2):

One option to extend the `SomeObject` too, something like this.

```js
var SomeObject = function(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b
}

SomeObject.prototype.toString = function(){
    return [ this.a, this.b ].join(' ')
};

SomeObject.prototype.split = function() {
   return String.prototype.split.apply(this.toString(), arguments);
};

var objInstance = new SomeObject('this', 'that');

console.log(objInstance + '')                // this that
//console.log(("" + objInstance).split(''))    // [ 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'a', 't' ]
console.log(objInstance.split(''));
```

In a comment you've asked:

> I was thinking about doing this programmatically by doing it for all functions - but is there a way to list all functions of an object?

Yes, you'd use `getOwnPropertyNames` on `String.prototype` and filter out the ones that aren't functions:

```js
var SomeObject = function(a, b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b
}

SomeObject.prototype.toString = function(){
    return [ this.a, this.b ].join(' ')
};

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String.prototype).forEach(function(name) {
    var fn = String.prototype[name];
    if (name !== "toString" && typeof fn === "function") {
        SomeObject.prototype[name] = function() {
            return fn.apply(this.toString(), arguments);
        };
    }
});

var objInstance = new SomeObject('this', 'that');

console.log(objInstance + '')                // this that
//console.log(("" + objInstance).split(''))    // [ 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 't', 'h', 'a', 't' ]
console.log(objInstance.split(''));
```

Comment: Interesting thought. I was thinking about doing this programmatically by doing it for all functions - but is there a way to lost all functions of an object?

Comment: @simone `lost all functions of an object` you mean? Do it only if you have custom requirements, doesn't makes sense if you do it for all the functions.

Comment: "lost" should have been "list" - list all functions of an object

Comment: @simone to handle all the functions of an object, you can use certainperformance's solution.

Comment: I was wondering about performance in using Proxy. Same as in setting the prototype in a deleted solution. But both look quite interesting...

Comment: @simone http://thecodebarbarian.com/thoughts-on-es6-proxies-performance seems to be slow here, It depends on your requirement how many functions you want to list down/ use them, according to that you can write custom function and use them. I think predefined and creating function based on that would be pretty too.

Comment: @simone - I've added to Just code's answer to show how you'd do all functions on `String.prototype` automatically.